# Nested expression in Freemarker

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I want to iterate over a list like this in freemarker:

```
<#assign count=myList?size>

<#list 0..count as i>
    ${myList[i].myProperty}
</#list>
```

I get an error from Freemarker saying:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression myList[i].myProperty is 
undefined on...
```

I have also tried:

```
${myList[${i}].myProperty}
```

I know I can do

```
<#list myList as items>
```

But I want to iterate over like in the top way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you just need the index, then you can do:

```
<#list myList as item>
  ${item?index} ${item}
</#list>
```

(Note that `?index` only exists since 2.3.23; before that, use the legacy `item_index` variable.)

You can also use `<#if limit < item_index><#break></#if>` to break out of the loop, if that's what's needed.

If you really need to iterate with an index, use `<#list 0..<count>` (that's an exclusive-end range expression there, `from ..< to`), as there's no item at the `count` index.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an exception because you are trying to get item with index equal to the size of the array. Lets say the size of `myList` collection is 3 then using numerical range sequence expression `0..sizeOfMyList` will produce indexes from `0` to `3`, and index `3` is out of bound for this collection.

So use `size-1` to get all items from the collection.

```
<#list 0..count-1 as i>
    ${myList[i].myProperty}
</#list>
```

BTW if you just need an index of current item inside `<#list>` there is special variable for that: `variableName_index`.

```
<#list myList as item>
  ${item_index}. ${item}
</#list>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail if your list is of size 0, because `0..-1` will generate `[0, -1]`, not `[]`.

Comment: @ddekany: Sure. And if `myList` is null it also fails. My answer answers OP question **why** this is happening and how to fix it. BTW I also mention exact solution that you propose.

Comment: Since then, 2.3.21 has introduced the exclusive-end range operator, which works even if `count` is 0: `<#list 0..<count as i>`

Comment: @ddekany: Nice. Good to know.